# How do I find my windows product key?

Tags: windows-vista, license-key

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I find out which product key was used to activate Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/171567/how-do-i-find-out-which-product-key-was-used-to-activate-windows)

I'm running Windows Vista now my Laptop came pre-installed with Vista and I have always used the recovery discs to format my system but I want to use a standard copy of vista and I no longer have my key, it rubbed off the bottom of my laptop so i removed it. Is there anyway i can get the key that my recovery discs use and will that be okay with a standard copy of vista home premium like the recovery discs install?

Comment: The `serial` tag here refers to serial ports, not serial numbers.

Comment: well it wouldn't let me use product key

Comment: On a note i found an old program thanks everyone but I have a windows product key and a windows default product key. Can i use them for a retail disc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Belarc Advisor](http://www.belarc.com/free_download.html).

Download, install, run it, then it opens a page in your web browser displaying *all kinds* of facts and statistics about your PC...near the bottom, it has all the product keys, etc for all the install software, and, of course, the operating system...Hope that helps!

Comment: thanks, but my main query now is will the serial key work on a standard copy of Win Vista 32bit because it will be the code my recovery discs install

Comment: yes, it should...if the key does not work, you can always call Microsoft and tell them the situation (that you are reinstalling Windows, and want to reuse the key, correct?)

Comment: The key probably will NOT work with retail Windows Vista.  OEM licenses (what computer makers buy) generally don't use keys that are compatible with retail purchases.

Answer (score 2):

[Magical Jelly Bean Keyfinder](http://www.magicaljellybean.com/keyfinder/) is the easiest method I've ever found. For Vista, OEM product keys (those that come with a system) are not compatible with retail discs.

Comment: so basically having the code doesn't make any difference because i'll still have to use the recovery discs :(.

Comment: +1 for Magical Jelly Bean Keyfinder. It's helped me many times with Windows re-installs :)

Answer (score 1):

Right click on Computer, go to Properties, and somewhere near the bottom should have your product key listed.

Comment: Thats my product ID not product key