# Recover lost Windows serial key

Tags: windows

I bought an Asus laptop which came with a copy of Windows 7. Long story short I lost the sticker which contained the serial key to my bought product. Should Asus be obliged to send me a serial key if I prove my purchase somehow? If not what could I do? Thanks

Comment: no asus is not obliged to do anything, but check this out http://www.magicaljellybean.com/keyfinder/

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I find out which product key was used to activate Windows?](http://superuser.com/questions/171567/how-do-i-find-out-which-product-key-was-used-to-activate-windows), [Recovering a Windows XP License key](http://superuser.com/questions/32367/recovering-a-windows-xp-license-key), [How to recover Windows Vista product key?](http://superuser.com/questions/301350/how-to-recover-windows-vista-product-key), [find the product key that was used to activate Windows 8?](http://superuser.com/questions/495794/how-can-i-find-the-product-key-that-was-used-to-activate-windows-8)

Comment: I wouldn't say they're "obliged", but it can't hurt to ask politely.

Comment: If this isn't a dupe of one of these, and it really is about whether Asus is obliged or not, then I'd say it's off topic (we're not lawyers :) )

Comment: @FrankThomas - My only experience with that program proved the application was a complete waste of money considering the authentication code it claims is my Windows Key isn't even correct.

Comment: I'm sorry you had a bad experience. it worked fine for me on Win7 Ultimate and enterprise with Technet keys.

Answer (score 0):

Forget wasting time proving you bought it- just extract the license key from Windows using free software.

Check this out:

Magical Jellybean keyfinder: http://www.magicaljellybean.com/keyfinder/

Comment: Neither the free version or the paid version display the correct serial key.  The product is a huge scam.

Answer (score 0):

Asus will not provide you with a serial key. However, they can provide you with your recovery media. This typically costs between $10-50 and will contain your windows operating system that came with your computer, as well as any drivers/software that came installed on your laptop when you purchased it.

The other user recommended Magical Jellybean keyfinder. I will tell you that I work for an IT company that does computer rebuilds daily, and I prefer Produkey Finder from Nirsoft. It is a very streamlined and superfast app. You can find it at: http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/product_cd_key_viewer.html

If your hard drive has crashed or you cannot boot into your OS for some reason, this may not be a viable option. If that is the case, I recommend ordering your CD from Asus. If you need to be back up immediatley, you can download your version of windows from this forum: http://www.digital-kaos.co.uk/forums/f94/original-untouched-windows-7-sp1-iso-32-bit-64-bit-220877/

You will need to activate within 30 days, but you can install and then activate once you get your CD with the correct serial number.